# @Dblookup and formatting on web

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I have been developing a web application using domino, therein I have dblookup-ing the field from notes client;  Now, this is working fine but the format of value is missing while using on web.

For example in lotus notes client the field value format is as above

1. I am one, I am two, I am one , I am two, labbblallalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalaallllal
2. Labbbaalalalallalalalalalaalallaal
3. Hello there, labblalalallalalalllaalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala

Now when I retrieve the value of the field on web it seems it takes 2 immediate after 1. and so forth, I was expecting line feed here which is not happening.

The field above is multi valued field.  Also on web I have used computed text which does db lookup from notes client.

Please help me what else could/alternate solution for this case.

Thanks
HD

Answer (score 1):

Your multi-valued field has display options associated with it and the Notes client honors those. Obviously, your options are set up to display entries separated by newlines.

The computed text that you are using for the web does not have options like that and the field options are irrelevant because you aren't displaying the field. Your code has to insert the @Newlines.  That's pretty easy because @DbLookup returns a list, and if you concatenate a list and a scalar, the scalar will be appended to each element of the list.  (Look at the third example under "concatenation, pairwise" [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/2a483322f7b71a4485256c54004bde56?OpenDocument) to see what I mean.

The way you've worded your question is a little unclear to me, but what you need in your computed text formula is either something like this:

```
list := @DbLookup(etc,. etc.);
list + @Newline;
```

Or something like this:

```
multiValueFieldContainingListWithDbLookupResult + @NewLine;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @implode(Dblookupreturnedvalue;"
");

thanks All :)